# Force Domain/ActiveDirectory authentication to take a long time for testing purpose

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012

We have an application that communicates with a domain controller for authentication. We need to simulate a situation where the authentication takes a very long time. Is there a way to trick the domain controller to suspend the authentication process for a specific time period? I read that there is an option to create a custom authentication DLL, I was wondering if there is something more simple.

Thanks :)

Comment: There is no way to "trick" the domain controller to suspend the authentication process for a specific time period.  But, there is a client side workaround to simulate this.  On the client, setup up fake DNS servers for the primary and secondary servers.  On Windows, you can have up to 25 DNS servers configured, last I heard.  So you can choose, how many fake DNS servers you want before it reaches the right one.  Make sure all the "fake" servers are IP addresses which do not resolve to anything, if any "DNS" server answers, client will stop there and take whatever answer given as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It sounds like a good workaround, but unfortunately it's a bit complicated, I need to be able to automate this process, it's possible but I was looking for something more simple. Thanks again :)

Comment: Your suggestion gave me another idea - disable the network card on the domain controller for the desired period when the app tries to authenticate so it will not be reachable. This seems to give me what I needed. Thanks!